# How do I identify the right gas to set in web3 send?

Tags: web3js, gas, gas-limit, gas-price, out-of-gas

This is my send code:

```
window.videoContract.methods
    .mint(account, 'https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmRQC1...')
    .send({
        from: account,
        gas: 20100000
    });
```

If I set it too high, I get this error:
ALERT: [ethjs-query] while formatting outputs from RPC '{"value":{"code":-32603,"data":{"code":-32000,"message":"exceeds block gas limit"}}}'

If I set it too low, the transaction fails with out of gas error:
https://explorer-mumbai.maticvigil.com/tx/0x79d96c3a0d9f920d75e17d034c3c0452b8b25fc3395d5595d9b2999fa0602f45/internal-transactions

Answer (score 2):

Usually it is safe to leave the gas estimation for the wallet itself and not to try to do it yourself.

In the case wallets cannot estimate the gas, which sometimes happens for complex transactions, you can do test transactions on testnet and figure out how many gas units the transactions spend and then use that as a hardcoded limit.

Comment: Something must have gone wrong with my contracts. If I take the gas and gasPrice settings out, I get this error in Metamask. "ALERT: Transaction Error. Exception thrown in contract code."

Comment: But does the transaction actually work?

Comment: No it doesn't. I found out that my contract json files in the web project was not updated, so it was not in sync with the latest version of the contract. All good now. Thanks.